# How to enable autocomplete/intellisense for query builder in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm working with my Laravel project on Visual Studio Code. I installed some extensions to keep my productivity growing with snippets, PHP intelliphense, Laravel extension pack, etc. However, the editor doesn't show intellisense/autocomplete when it comes to writing Query Builders in Laravel. Here is an example:

No Intellisense for 'where'

[image]
As you can see in the picture, I want to write 'where' next to the arrow but no Intellisense. It would greatly enhance my productivity if the editor would show all kinds of possibilities straight of the bat instead of me surfing to Laravel docs to find the query builder I need.

Answer (score 0):

I use this, hope it solves your query: 
You can install this via VScode extension marketplace. simply search with

Laravel Extension Pack. Author is Winnie Lin

```
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onecentlin.laravel-extension-pack
```

Comment: I had this for a long time. It doesn't provide intellisense for query builders.

Answer (score 0):

Use Laravel 5 Snippets extension from vscode marketplace.

You can use other extensions of laravel as well, like blade snippets, go-to route etc.